# Getting Values Using API and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I make my first project with API. I need add this to my project: https://dokumentacja-inpost.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/PL/pages/18153479/1.7.3+Shipment+Tracking

I use in my project Laravel 8.

I make composer require michalbiarda/shipx-php-sdk

And I added this code to my controller"

```
$status = new \MB\ShipXSDK\Method\Tracking\Read;
$status->tracking_number = 123;
dd($status);
```

but its return:

```
MB\ShipXSDK\Method\Tracking\Read {#1599 ▼
  +"tracking_number": 123
}
```

Not status :(

How can I get status from inputs by this API?

Please help me

Comment: Looks like you instantiated the class, initialised a property, but you didnt tell the object to actually GoGoGo and get the response

Comment: How can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to hit a curl request with required attributes.
[image: Screen shot of the following curl]

You can dd() the response of the curl response and surely you ll get the status.

Comment: Ok, this working when I make this code:
$url = 'https://api-shipx-pl.easypack24.net/v1/tracking/605850699284230016546816';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r(json_decode($result));
        echo '</pre>';
but if I want use this API? Can you show me how?

Comment: Yes you just need to add original url i(https://api-shipx-pl.easypack24.net/) before the api and should work :- https://api-shipx-pl.easypack24.net/v1/tracking/:tracking_number this should be the exact url for this :)